# Rcpp compilation on windows fails (64bit)

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to set up Rcpp on my Windows machine (have not had issues on my unix box).

I have installed R in C:/opt/R/current (a Google search suggested that spaces in installation paths could give trouble), and I have installed Rtools.
I have the simple cpp file:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int timesTwo(int x) {
   return x * 2;
}
```

and an R file:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("cppfile.cpp")
```

I get the following error:

```
C:/opt/R/current/etc/x64/Makeconf:196: warning: overriding recipe for target `.m.o' C:/opt/R/current/etc/x64/Makeconf:189: warning: ignoring old recipe for target `.m.o' C:\MINGW3~1\bin\make.exe: Interrupt/Exception caught (code = 0xc0000005, addr = 0x0x750343f9) Warning message: running command 'make -f "C:/opt/R/current/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/opt/R/current/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="sourceCpp_67515.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="cppfile.o"' had status 255  
Error in sourceCpp("cppfile.cpp") : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: Install e.g. `dplyr` from github via `devtools` works fine (and does quite a lot of compiling Rcpp stuff).

**UPDATE**: I added the Rtools bin dir to PATH, and now I get another error which seems to relate to 32/64bit:

```
g++ -m64 -I"C:/opt/R/current/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/opt/R/current/library/Rcpp/include"  -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c cppfile.cpp -o cppfile.o cppfile.cpp:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in make: *** [cppfile.o] Error 1 Warning message: running command 'make -f "C:/opt/R/current/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/opt/R/current/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="sourceCpp_41862.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="cppfile.o"' had status 2  
Error in sourceCpp("cppfile.cpp") : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

Comment: As an aside, its not true that R needs to be installed on a path with no spaces.  I use Rcpp and have R installed in the `C:\Program Files` tree.  I do install Rtools in `C:\Rtools` which has no spaces.

Comment: Yeah, I did that too. I also tried with my regular R install in "Program Files"...

Comment: @G.Grothendieck it is no a must but we have been fighting this for as long as Rcpp has existed, and some users gets failures more easily if they do. We sanitize the path where we can but it is not failsafe. Also note that the R-on-Windows FAQ itself recommends to not install in a path with spaces.  Which the R Installer still does.  The best defense is *still* to override that.

Comment: The Windows version of R has improved over time so if you have been doing this for a long time and are still using the same strategies you used some time ago its likely out of date.  Both Rtools & Windows default user library do not have spaces in their path anyways.  Its best to stick to the standard installation and then you will have the least trouble and that implies that there will be spaces in the path to R.  If you know of a situation where putting R in the C:\Program Files tree causes problems in Windows for Rcpp please demonstrate it since my experience is that it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that I needed to add both the RTools/bin and the Rtools/gcc-x.y.z/bin to PATH. Now things work smoothly.

Comment: If you use `devtools` or Rstudio, they'll set the path for you.

Comment: I do use both devtools and Rstudio, however I had to add the path manually to make things work. Before I did that, installing from github using devtools did work, even when cpp compilation was necessary. It was only my "own" small example which did not work.

Comment: The installer for Rtools automatically sets the path correctly for you including both the path to the bin directory and the path to the gcc* directory so you presuably turned that off when you installed Rtools.

Comment: Yes, that worked for me too!!, in a windows server with no acces to internet nor the C: drive, etc. The way it worked was using devtools in an R file : `add_path("E:\\dir_to_r_tools"); add_path("E:\\dir_to_r_tools\\bin");add_path("E:\\dir_to_r_tools\\gcc-4.6.3\\bin");`, where E is the drive you put r-tools folder. Notice the `\\` and the tree paths to add. You must do  this "adding" for each R session... i think.